# How to update a div with another image in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my directive the example I was looking at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybcNosdPA76J1IqXjcGG?p=preview) uses `<a href="#" ...` to put the new image in the container div. I've tried to create that same functionality in my directive but when I click my images it doesn't change my `pictBox` div.  Could I be missing stuff in my css file?  Why is the background-image text there? This is my directive:

```
app.directive('smallPictureBox', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            index: '=index',
            item: '=itemdata'
        },
        template: '<a href="#"><img src="{{item.url}}"/></a>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            if (parseInt(scope.index)==0) {
                angular.element(attrs.options).css({'background-image':'url('+ scope.item.url +')'});
            }

            elem.bind('click', function() {
                var src = elem.find('img').attr('src');

                angular.element(attrs.options).css({'background-image':'url('+ scope.item.url +')'});
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

This is what my html looks like:

```
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="pictureBox">
    <div id="pictBox">
      <img ng-src="{{primaryImage.url}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lowerPictureBox">
    <div ng-repeat="image in item.images" options='#pictBox' itemdata='image' index="$index"     class="smallPictureBox">
      <img ng-src="{{image.url}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can make it so that when I click a picture in the lowerPictureBox it displays it in the pictureBox?

Comment: hard to help when you provide a link to a demo that works, but not to one using your code that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i could not replicate your total example but i have a set up a small working code which displays image on top when u click bottom image this could help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body ng-controller="main">
        <div class="shadow">
  <div class="pictureBox">
    <div id="pictBox">
      <img ng-src="{{primaryImage.url}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lowerPictureBox">
   <div small linksrc="primaryImage"></div>
  </div>
</div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("demo", []);
            app.controller('main', function ($scope) {
                $scope.primaryImage = { url: '' };
            });
            app.directive('small', [function () {
                return {
                    scope: { src: '=linksrc' },
                    replace:true,
                    template:"<img ng-src='http://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-small.png'>",
                    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                        elem.bind("click", function () {
                            scope.src.url = 'http://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-small.png';
                            scope.$apply();
                        });

                    }
                }
            }]);


        </script>
</body>

</html>
```